# mysql - validate/correct based on date format

Tags: mysql, validation

I'm querying a mysql database where string fields are being used to enter date information (this is due to configured 3rd party application that is importing the data.)  I recently ran into an issue where I am using the following to query 2 different fields.  If the first is Null then it moves onto the next, and then reports an error if both are null:

```
IFNULL(IFNULL(NULLIF(DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(REPLACE(so.customfields->>'$."59".value',"-","/"),'%m/%d/%Y'),'%m-%d-%Y'), "00-00-0000"), NULLIF(DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(REPLACE(so.customfields->>'$."61".value',"-","/"),'%m/%d/%Y'),'%m-%d-%Y'), "00-00-0000")), "Missing Requested Ship and Earliest Ship Date") as "Earliest Ship Date",
```

This works great if the format is correct, for example: "6/24/2022" or "6-24-2022"

The issue that I ran into today is that a user input error caused the result to be null for custom field 59 due to the user input: "6/24//2022"

Does anyone know a method to validate that the date format is correct, and if not to remove extra characters like the extra "/" so that it is correct?

Comment: You can use `replace(XXX, '//', '/')` to combine them into a single `/`.

Comment: Ha, thats what I wound up doing...  I guess I'm wondering if there are any other methods to ensure the format is mm/dd/yyyy and to remove any extra "/" or other characters...

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any built-in way to do flexible date parsing.

Comment: I would recommend doing the cleanup directly in the DB after importing, rather than in your queries.

Comment: I wish I had the time, and personnel to do that.  This query runs daily, and orders are entered daily, so it's would be a full time job to keep up with it.  The unfortunate thing is that this field is a string field and it's user input, then goes through an integration (hence why it's needs to be a string) and then it gets to the query.  If the user (who is a third party vendor) enters the info incorrectly, then I'm stuck with what they give me.  I wish I could force the date field, but the integration requires it to be a string field :(

Comment: You said it was imported, so I thought there was a periodic file import, not continuous user entry. But why can't they use an entry form with a datepicker instead of text entry?